# How to convert bash file to a binary executable

Tags: binary, executable

I created a binary executable from bash script on linux server through SHC. The binary created works fine on linux machines, but through mistake on Mac. How could I convert my bash file to binary executable that is able to run everywhere(ubuntu, CentOS, Mac, Cygwin)?

```
    shc -v -r -T -f ir16fetcher.sh
    mv ir16fetcher.sh.x ir16fetcher
```

Shebang of my bash script

```
    #!/bin/bash
```

On Linux machines

```
    ./ir16installer 
    USAGE  : ir16fetcher <servername/ip address> [the n th latest build - optional. Default 1]
    EXAMPLE: ir16fetcher jagger 2
    EXAMPLE: ir16fetcher 167.116.6.155
    REQUIRE: Please make sure conf file in installation folder ~/IRinstall/ir16 & ~/IRinstall/irmanager
```

On my Mac

```
    ./ir16installer 
    -bash: ./ir16installer: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Linux binary wouldn't work on Mac.  Create the binary on Mac.  BTW, why do need to create binaries for shell scripts?

Comment: For the mac add .command extension to allow the execution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this for every architecture and operating system you need to support. In any case, there doesn't really seem to be any benefits of using this method for distribution. It adds dependencies and complicates delivery, and I'm pretty sure whatever obfuscation the "shc" compiler implements is easily reversed.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not gonna work

> "*The compiled binary will still be  dependent  on  the  shell
>        specified  in  the  first  line  of  the  shell  code  (i.e.
>        #!/bin/sh), thus shc does not create completely  independent
>        binaries."*

From http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html

Answer (score 1):

if the goal here is to "hide" your source code, and then have the "hidden" copy of the code be executable on the Unix OSes you listed, then, encryption is really your only option.

I say this because encryption tools are available on every base Unix install.  For your purposes, this is a very good thing as you wont have to download or configure anything additional.  They're just there, as part of the natural installation of the OS.  One of such tools is called openssl.

**To Encrypt your file/script with openssl:**

```
echo precious-content | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -salt -k mypassword
U2FsdGVkX1+K6tvItr9eEI4yC4nZPK8b6o4fc0DR/Vzh7HqpE96se8Fu/BhM314z
```

**To Decrypt your file/script with openssl:**

```
echo U2FsdGVkX1+K6tvItr9eEI4yC4nZPK8b6o4fc0DR/Vzh7HqpE96se8Fu/BhM314z | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -k mypassword
precious-content
```

Now, to get openssl to do what you want it to do automatically without having to spend hours of your own time figuring out a way, you can paste your script to a site like [www.EnScryption.com](http://www.EnScryption.com).  This site will generate an "executable" version of your code for you, which you can then run on any Mac, Ubuntu, RedHat, CentOS box.