# What are the compiled shell files written in for linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

So this may seem a little bit of a low level question but what in gods name are the bash scripts written in. Are they written in any language that can be compiled down to a binary file or are they written in the bash script then compiled.

I'm trying to create a script to do some automated printing and text file editing with a text file that has a format that I know and can edit. Basically I am trying to create a script that will run constantly and execute a python file monthly get the new edited file and print it.

Comment: bash scripts are in plain text, as already explained by Basile's answer. However, you can convert to binary using `shc` - [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230262/how-to-convert-bash-file-to-a-binary-executable)

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/bash` is an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29), not a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). And it has to be an interpreter, because the shell standard (Posix `sh`) requires a lot of *interpreted* constructs (e.g. `$(`...`)` etc....) and is mostly working on strings.

On some Linux distributions `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash` which is a slightly faster implementation of the Posix `sh`. On other Linux distributions `/bin/sh` is `/bin/bash`

`bash` scripts (starting with `#!/bin/bash`) are interpreted by `/bin/bash` (which is an ELF executable).

To execute something monthly use a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry.